# Help with solving indefinite integral

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I am working on this problem, attempting to find the indefinite integral:
$$\int9(\sqrt[5]{2x})dx$$
I can manage to get up to here:
$$=9(2^{1\over 5})({5\over 6}x^\frac{6}{5})+C$$
But I don't know how to get to here (The Solution):
$$=\frac{15x^\frac{6}{5}}{2^{4\over 5}}+C$$
If anyone could provide an explanation as to how I get from where I am, to the solution, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's just some algebraic simplification. Your answer is the same as what you call "The Solution".

Comment: You had the $x$ outside the root, I fixed it for you.

Comment: $9(2^{1\over 5})({5\over 6})=\frac{9\times 5}6 2^{1\over 5}=\frac{15}2 2^{1\over 5}=\frac{15}{2^{4\over 5}}$

Comment: $2^{-1} 2^{1/5} = 2^{1/5-1} =2^{1/5-5/5}=2^{-4/5}$

Answer (score 1):

As a gentle reminder, please note that, by the first fundamental theorem of calculus, the indefinite integral of a function is a primitive of the function. So it is better to call $\int f$ a primitive of a function $f$.

Regarding the original question, we have $\int 9\cdot 2^{1/5}\cdot x^{1/5} dx = 15\cdot 2^{-4/5}\cdot x^{6/5} +$ const.

Answer (score 0):

write 6=2.3 then get cancel nominator 9 by denominator 3 and multiply it by present 5 in nominator you will get 15. And then handelout 2 by (2)^1/5 you will get (2)^4/5 in the denominator